OSError: (WinError) 126 The specified module could not be found. Error loading
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model from scratch
model.train(data="data.yaml", epochs=1)  # train the model

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Projects\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ultralytics import YOLO
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\ultralytics\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ultralytics.data.explorer.explorer import Explorer
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\ultralytics\data\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import BaseDataset
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\ultralytics\data\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Thank you for helping me solve this problem

you are probably missing CUDA or you have wrong version.

error shows problem with shm.dll - so first check if you have it. Next search on Google if someone else had problem with shm.dll because it may need some other C/C++ libraries which you have to install on your own.

Yeah, please search for the error message first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=126+shm.dll.
